# Symfony 2.8 debug toolbar renders empty

Tags: symfony, toolbar

I found my debug toolbar has almost empty content:

```
<div id="sfToolbarMainContent-c7947c" class="sf-toolbarreset clear-fix" data-no-turbolink>

<a class="hide-button" title="Close Toolbar" tabindex="-1" accesskey="D" onclick="
    var p = this.parentNode;
    p.style.display = 'none';
    (p.previousElementSibling || p.previousSibling).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('sfMiniToolbar-c7947c').style.display = 'block';
    Sfjs.setPreference('toolbar/displayState', 'none');
">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#AAAAAA" d="M21.1,18.3c0.8,0.8,0.8,2,0,2.8c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6s-1-0.2-1.4-0.6L12,14.8l-6.3,6.3
c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6s-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.8-0.8-0.8-2,0-2.8L9.2,12L2.9,5.7c-0.8-0.8-0.8-2,0-2.8c0.8-0.8,2-0.8,2.8,0L12,9.2
l6.3-6.3c0.8-0.8,2-0.8,2.8,0c0.8,0.8,0.8,2,0,2.8L14.8,12L21.1,18.3z"/>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
```

[image]

instead of the correct one (You may see this by accessing the route `/app_dev.php/_wdt/78273e`, where `78273e` - is an example hash):

[image]

No JS and page errors, all tags body are OK. 
Have no idea when did it become broken. 
Did anybody face with such a case?

Comment: just in case: you dont override the profiler template in app/config/Resources ?

Comment: @ivoba of course, no :)